# Large linear programs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, ampl

I have a linear program with order N^4 variables and order N^4 constraints. If I want to solve this in AMPL, I define the constraints one by one without having to bother about the exact coefficient matrices. No memory issues arises. When using the standard LP-solver in Matlab however, I need to define the matrices explicitly.

When I have variables with four subscripts, this will lead to a massively sparse matrix of dimension order N^4 x N^4. This matrix won't even fit in memory for non trivial problem sizes.

Is there a way to get around this problem using Matlab, apart from various column generation/cutting plane techniques? Since AMPL manages to solve it, I suppose they're either automating some kind of decomposition, or they somehow solve the LP without explicitly working with this sparse monster matrix.

Comment: did you have a look at MATLAB's [`sparse`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrices?

Comment: @m.s. Consider making this an answer, I will upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

MATLAB supports sparse matrices using the [`sparse`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) command which allows you to build your constraint matrix without exceeding memory limits.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `sparse` mentioned by m.s. you can also use [AMPL API](http://ampl.com/products/api/) for MATLAB. It is especially useful if you already have an AMPL model and want to work with it from MATLAB.